# Migrating from jcenter to maven gives error: "Failed to resolve: org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:4.4.0"

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, jcenter

I am trying to use this in my Android app:

https://github.com/adblockplus/libadblockplus-android

bu putting this in my build.gradle:

`implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:4.4.0'`

It works fine if I have `jcenter()` listed in my build.gradle repositories. But I keep getting the warning `JCenter is at end of life` and so am trying to switch to `maven`.

But when I replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`, it doesn't work and gives me error:

`Failed to resolve: org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:4.4.0`

I can see that the library is available on Maven here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.adblockplus/adblock-android-webview/4.4.0

But yet Android Studio is unable to find it for some reason.

What am I doing wrong? I am very new to this so not familiar with repositories much.

Comment: That page you linked specifically says the the artifact is available only on jcenter.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Why does Maven show it then? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.adblockplus/adblock-android-webview/4.4.0

Comment: That's `mvnrepository.com`, not the [maven central search](https://search.maven.org/). What makes you think those are related to one another?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am very new to this. So Maven and Maven Central are different things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's available in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/, then you can use `mavenCentral()`. Otherwise it's not there in `mavenCentral()`.

https://mvnrepository.com just tells you which artifacts are available where. If you see at the bottom of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.adblockplus/adblock-android-webview/4.4.0, it says "This artifact is located at JCenter repository (https://jcenter.bintray.com/)".

In the attached pics, you can see which repo they are available. Adblock is present only in Jcenter. Whereas Apache Commons is present only in Central and not in JCenter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, that explains it. Thank you.